# How do you save and open a Java program with a Java program?

Tags: java

So I've done a little searching and Google and the StackOverflow search brings up nothing regarding this question. I thought I had found something a moment ago but it just wanted to know how to open a .exe with Java.

Anyway as the title says I would like to know how to compile and save a Java file from within a Java program and then open that same Java file I just saved.

So yeah any help with this would be greatly appreciated thanks.

EDIT:Okay what I'm talking about is to have the Java file execute.

The idea I have is using a genetic algorithm as the base and a whole lot of learning I have to yet do. Program a program that can create programs within given parameters. That would then launch itself and continue the cycle of improving itself. Basically self improving code. At the moment I have the base code of the genetic algorithm and am just trying to learn how it works as it was a tutorial I found. Yes I know it may not be possible but I like the challenge and it gives me a goal and a in my opinion fun reason to learn Java as I have attempted to before but I didn't get very far.

Anyway sorry for any confusion.

Edit2: So this is basically the code being used it has been slightly modified and messed around with though at the moment to see what I can get it to do already: http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/creating-a-genetic-algorithm-for-beginners/3

Comment: Can you please let us know what have you tried so far? It will help all people here help you.

Comment: What do you mean by **open an .exe**? Do you actually mean **execute an .exe**? And a Java file is like any other file, so what's the exact problem you're facing?

Comment: You can use `ant` to build file(jar,..) and then run program by using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`

Comment: You mean, help you pro bono via private e-mail? That's not how we work: it's all about public display of competence around here :) But if you learn how to write questions that we appreciate, you can write as many as you want.

Comment: **Anyway as the title says I would like to know how to compile and save a Java file from within a Java program and then open that same Java file I just saved.** ***is just confusing***

Comment: >>At the moment I have the base code of the genetic algorithm and am just trying to learn how it works as it was a tutorial I found.<< A link, or a dump, to/of the code you are talking about would be very, very, very helpful :O

Answer (score 2):

You can try taking a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html.

Answer (score 1):

After your edit, I understood that your question is:

**How can I write a java program that is clever enough to create more clever java programs?**

It is going to be a difficult task. If you have the solution for the artificial intelligence that is necessary for this, then you need a technical solution for how to dynamically create a new class in runtime. I can suggest two options for that.

1. Use the [java compiler API](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/)
2. Or use the [javassist](http://www.jboss.org/javassist) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/ to start processes from Java code. You should call the same things as you would form command line. (`javac -cp...` and then `java -cp.. someclass`)

Comment: I think you'd better use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac -cp... someclass") or any of its variant instead because it is directly included in the JDK.

Comment: Please, allow me to disagree :) Just because something is in the JDK doesn't mean it is the best solution... Apache Commons are one of the best libs available and this one was specifically designed to execute processes from Java, so it offers much more then the Runtime.exec().

Comment: Well, I don't mean you always have to use things from the JDK, but I think it is good to not add new dependencies when it is not necessary (as it seems to be IMHO). If in this case it appears  you have an interest to use commons-exec then why not?

Comment: If all you need to launch a simple command, then the built-in method will be sufficient. However if you want to monitor the process, you don't want to mess with escaping the arguments (as the classpath) then you probably should go with Apache commons-exec.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public class MyProg 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String fname = "Prog1.java";
        BufferedWriter bw;

        try{
            bw = new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter(fname)
            );
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot open " + fname + "!");
            return;
        }


        final String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        bw.write("public class Prog1{" + NL
                + "\tpublic static void main(String[] args) {" + NL
                + "\t\tSystem.out.println(\"hello world\");" + NL
                + "\t}" + NL
                + "}" + NL
        );
        bw.close();

        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(fname)
            );
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(fname + " not found!");
            return;
        }

        String line;
        while( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }





        Process p1 = new ProcessBuilder(
            "javac", "Prog1.java"
        ).start();

        int error = p1.waitFor();
        System.out.println("p1: " + error);

        /*
        Process p2 = new ProcessBuilder(
            "java", "-cp . Prog1"
        ).start();

        error = p2.waitFor();

        System.out.println("p2: " + error);
        */

        FileInputStream fin;
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(fname);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(fname + " not found!");
            return;
        }

        int abyte;
        while((abyte = fin.read()) != -1)
        {
            System.out.println(abyte);
        }

        fin.close();


    }
} 


--output:--
public class Prog1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
p1: 0
112
117
98
108
105
99
...
...
125
10
```

Comment: Thank you that code has helped me get halfway to what I want to do in no time at all.